# run .exe (or other file like .bat or .cfg) from xml

Tags: xml

I bought an ActionScript 3 menu. It creates buttons with help of a xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
<item id="0" name="TEST" url="xml/test.exe" target="_blank"/>
</data>
```

But all links opening my browser. Even a workaround with bat-files did not work.
It would be great to be able to run files like "game.exe"

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot do that.

Comment: Hi Evan, so I have to find out how Internet Explorer 11 (or an other browser - I need it only for a local Interface, so does not have to be the newest or safest) can be set up in that way, that it automatically runs a file (.exe or .bat).

Comment: creating any type of link like that would usually popup a download dialog.